# How do I change the top bar font in GNOME 3.30.1?

Tags: themes, fonts, gnome-shell, top-bar

I am desperately trying to change the font of my top bar, but editing the gnome-shell.css in my currently installed theme (Canta-dark-square) does not work somehow. My .themes folder is in the `/home/my_name/` directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

to make entire top bar items size:

change the content in your gnome-shell.css file under .themes folder like below, put any value for your preferred font-size.

```
/* TOP BAR */
#panel {
  background-color: rgba(39, 42, 42, 0.85);
  /* transition from solid to transparent */
  transition-duration: 250ms;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 2em;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

[image]